# The result of running time calculated by Python is not correct

Tags: python

I trying to use time to record running time of this function, but i think the result is not correct, sometimes it will only cost 0s and the result is not stable.[The first two result is for N=10000， the third one is N=30000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyYpb.png)

```
import time
def sumOfN(n):
    start=time.time()
    theSum=0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        theSum=theSum+i
    end=time.time()
    return theSum,end-start
for i in range(5):
    print("Sum is %d required %10.7f seconds"%sumOfN(300000))
```

Comment: look into the `timeit` module

Comment: Your code looks fine to me... I don't think the code shown could ever cause that bug that you are seeing.

Comment: I also don't think the code is wrong. But the result is wired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the Python manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time):

> ### `time.time()`
>
> Return the time in seconds since the epoch as a floating
>   point number. Note that even though the time is always returned as a
>   floating point number, **not all systems provide time with a better
>   precision than 1 second**. While this function normally returns
>   non-decreasing values, it can return a lower value than a previous
>   call if the system clock has been set back between the two calls.

<sub><sup>(emphasis mine)</sup></sub>

It seems the timer resolution of your system is not enough to correctly measure the elapsed time of the function.  It actually looks like the precision is about 0.016, about 1/60 of a second, which is typical of Windows systems.

your approach has the following two problems:

- `time.time()` returns the current time (as in time of day), which can vary by auto-adjusting processes such as NTP or if someone modifies it (either by hand or via code).  *Use [`time.perf_counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) (or `time.clock()` in Python <3.3) instead*.
- You are measuring *one* execution of the function.  This can give you very wrong results due to the non-deterministic nature of garbage collection, bytecode optimization, and other quirks of languages like Python.  You should look into the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module instead.